# Merge sort algorithm sort time and swap count

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I have created a program where numbers are generated randomly for a list/ array. In this list, I need to calculate how long it will take to sort the list and also the number of swaps it will take to sort.

The below is my code. The code solves the list without any issue but the time and swap counter aren't working properly it just gives me `0,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,2,4` like results.

Am I doing something wrong when adding to `count` and also at the `start.time and end.time`

```
import random
import time
#X--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Random Number Generator
def random_generator():
    randomNumber = random.randint(0, 1000)
    return randomNumber
#X--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def arraygenerator():
    arr = []
    for draw in range(15):
        randomNumber = random_generator()
        arr.append(randomNumber)
    print ("Unsorted Array is : ", arr)
    return arr

def counter(count):
    return count



def merge(S1, S2, S):
  start = time.time()
  count = 0
  
  i = j = 0
  while i + j < len(S):
    if j == len(S2) or (i < len(S1) and S1[i] < S2[j]):
      S[i+j] = S1[i]      
      i += 1
      count +=1
      
    else:
      S[i+j] = S2[j]      
      j += 1
  end = time.time()
  print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")
  print(counter(count)) 
def merge_sort(S):
  
  
  n = len(S)
  if n < 2:
    return               
  
  mid = n // 2
  S1 = S[0:mid]          
  S2 = S[mid:n]           
  
  merge_sort(S1)        
  merge_sort(S2)          
  merge(S1, S2, S)        

def main():
  print('The list S1 to be sorted.....')
  s1 = arraygenerator()
  merge_sort(s1)

  print('The sorted list is ', s1)

  
main()
```

When I run the code my output is

```
The list S1 to be sorted.....
Unsorted Array is :  [697, 126, 983, 400, 400, 583, 166, 343, 517, 819, 265, 193, 362, 993, 876]
Runtime of the program is 0.0
1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
2
Runtime of the program is 0.0
3
Runtime of the program is 0.0
1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
2
Runtime of the program is 0.0
1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
2
Runtime of the program is 0.0
4
Runtime of the program is 0.0
7
The sorted list is  [126, 166, 193, 265, 343, 362, 400, 400, 517, 583, 697, 819, 876, 983, 993]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `counter` method ?

Comment: time shows `0` because it execute very fast

Comment: the `counter` method is to return the count

Comment: counter method does nothing, it returns what you pass to it